# Remote Desktop into Service Fabric local cluster

Tags: networking, azure-service-fabric, rdp

I'm trying to debug an issue with a Service Fabric node, and I want to RDP into the node in order to read internal log data.

However, I'm deploying to a local cluster, and I access my development machine via RDP. If I try to RDP into localhost from my development machine I of course see `you already have a console session in progress`, I'm already connected to this machine...

How can I remote desktop into a locally-running service fabric node when RDP is running on the host machine?

Comment: And with a local cluster you mean a cluster running on your development PC?

Comment: Correct. running on dev pc using Local Cluster Manager. and I access my dev pc via RDP

Comment: But you cannot rdp into the nodes. The node is virtual. Not a VM or somekind but each service is just a process on that machine so what is it you want to use RDP for?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, I thought nodes were generally treated as a machine I could RDP into. took this from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-remote-connect-to-azure-cluster-node

Comment: @fafrd as stated in the document you've provided this is true only if **Service Fabric cluster running in Azure**. So you have to look for logs on the dev box.